# Play rtsp stream from webcam using Gstreamer

Tags: linux, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to stream video from an IP camera [TS-WPTCAM](https://www.iodata.jp/product/lancam/lancam/ts-wptcam/).
I can directly stream the video in vlc using `rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp` but when i try with Gstreamer, it does not play the video.
Below is the output.

```
Lnx-Workstation:~$ gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp" name=demux demux. ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! rtph264depay ! autovideosink sync=false

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayGBM\)\ gldisplaygbm0";
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp
0:00:20.130738709 13686 0x5632fcf9d2d0 ERROR                default gstrtspconnection.c:1004:gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response: failed to connect: Socket I/O timed out
0:00:20.130840128 13686 0x5632fcf9d2d0 ERROR                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4702:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<demux> Could not connect to server. (Generic error)
0:00:20.130850670 13686 0x5632fcf9d2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7469:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<demux> error: Failed to connect. (Generic error)
0:00:20.130893392 13686 0x5632fcf9d2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7548:gst_rtspsrc_open:<demux> can't get sdp
0:00:20.130917551 13686 0x5632fcf9d2d0 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5628:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<demux> we are not connected
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux: Could not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(7469): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I also tried to play the video using `playbin` like this:

```
Lnx-Workstation:~$ gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp uridecodebin0::source::latency=100

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: latency = 100
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstRTSPSrc\)\ source"
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp
0:00:20.040912220 13549 0x55e2654b5e80 ERROR                default gstrtspconnection.c:1004:gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response: failed to connect: Socket I/O timed out
0:00:20.041032034 13549 0x55e2654b5e80 ERROR                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4702:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<source> Could not connect to server. (Generic error)
0:00:20.041058980 13549 0x55e2654b5e80 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7469:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<source> error: Failed to connect. (Generic error)
0:00:20.041160200 13549 0x55e2654b5e80 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7548:gst_rtspsrc_open:<source> can't get sdp
0:00:20.041185827 13549 0x55e2654b5e80 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5628:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<source> we are not connected
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(7469): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

*** Playbin for a file source works.

How can I play RTSP video using GStreamer?

EDIT:
As per Gregory's answer:

```
Lnx-Workstation:~$ gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp" ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp
0:00:20.108314006  3310 0x563cd86e8850 ERROR                default gstrtspconnection.c:1004:gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response: failed to connect: Socket I/O timed out
0:00:20.108425505  3310 0x563cd86e8850 ERROR                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4702:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<rtspsrc0> Could not connect to server. (Generic error)
0:00:20.108449668  3310 0x563cd86e8850 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7469:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<rtspsrc0> error: Failed to connect. (Generic error)
0:00:20.108540016  3310 0x563cd86e8850 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7548:gst_rtspsrc_open:<rtspsrc0> can't get sdp
0:00:20.108569689  3310 0x563cd86e8850 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5628:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> we are not connected
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not open resource for reading and writing.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(7469): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The error seems to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are `depay`loading `H264` from `RTP`, but you forgot to parse and decode it before passing it to `autovideosink`. I also don't know why you need the `demux` part, because you use only video and only one stream.
Try the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.100.50:19112/ipcam_h264.sdp" ! queue max-size-buffers=2 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Comment: I updated the command, but the error still persists. I updated the question.

Comment: It seems that GStreamer fails to connect to the RTSP server. Are you sure that the same RTSP address works with VLC?

Comment: yes, I have tested several times and on another Linux pc as well.
Could there be any other reason, like GStreamer is blocked by the camera?

Comment: I would use Wireshark to compare the RTSP communication when you use VLC to the RTSP communication when you use GStreamer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for your case, but IIRC there may be RTSP authentication problems with some gstreamer versions if plugins-ugly is installed. You may try:

```
sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

If not enough you may share the sdp for further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mplayer` here:

```
mplayer rtsp://username:password@IPADDRESS:PORT/your-path-to-stream
```